# MFC class CEditView font size

Tags: c++, mfc

I create visual studio (MFC) , multi documents using CEditView.

how to change font size in CEditView?

[image]

Comment: Can help better if you want all of your CEditViews to have the same font size, or if you want a different font in each CEditView.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample:

```
CFont* pFont = _ed.GetFont();
LOGFONT LogFont;
pFont->GetLogFont(&LogFont);

CFont* NewFont = new CFont();
// lstrcpy( LogFont.lfFaceName, _T("Times New Roman CE" ));
LogFont.lfHeight = 8;
NewFont->CreateFontIndirect(&LogFont);
_ed.SetFont(NewFont );
```

Comment: Won't that cause a memory leak?

Comment: Yes it will cause a memory leak.

Comment: I cannot build success for _ed.GetFont();

Comment: _ed is variable defining my controll. You have to use your.
And to avoid memory leak as mentioned above remember to use: delete NewFont. so NewFont should be member variable in dialog. And You could use delete NewFont for example in dioalog destructor.

Comment: I cannot use  _ed. What is this?

Comment: its example name of variable which in my case is CEdit. In Your case it will be other variable name, or even You may have no variable connected to You text container yet.